# gem bulk_insert: undefined method `result_sets' for nil:NilClass?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bulkinsert

I'm using gem bulk_insert for the first time: https://github.com/jamis/bulk_insert

I successfully used the gem to bulk copy records from one table to another. Later on, I needed to report the number of new records. I don't see anyway to get a row count back from `bulk_insert`, so I turned to `return_primary_keys` and `result_sets` to get a count, as shown in the Readme.

I added `inserted =` to line 3 and added the last line below:

```
columns = %i[first_name, last_name, email, referal]

inserted = User.bulk_insert(*columns, ignore: true, return_primary_keys: true) do |bulk|
  bulk.set_size = BATCH_SIZE

  registrants.select(:fname, :lname, :email).find_in_batches(batch_size: BATCH_SIZE) do |batch|
    batch.each do |reg|
      bulk.add [reg.fname, reg.lname, reg.email, 'self-registered']
    end
  end
end

puts "added #{inserted.result_sets.count} self-registered users"
```

Now, I get `NoMethodError: undefined method 'result_sets' for nil:NilClass` on the `puts` line.

I've read the Readme several times and searched for the problem with no results. Also checked that I've got the latest version - 1.7.0

What am I missing? How can I get to `result_sets`? Or better yet, can I get a record count without retrieving the entire list of new primary keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this issue on the repo](https://github.com/jamis/bulk_insert/issues/35#issuecomment-407368297), you need to create a `bulk_insert` worker first. So, in your case I think it would look something like this:

```
columns = %i[first_name, last_name, email, referal]

insert_worker = User.bulk_insert(*columns, ignore: true, return_primary_keys: true)

insert_worker.set_size = BATCH_SIZE

registrants.select(:fname, :lname, :email).find_in_batches(batch_size: BATCH_SIZE) do |batch|
  batch.each do |reg|
    insert_worker.add [reg.fname, reg.lname, reg.email, 'self-registered']
  end
end

puts "added #{insert_worker.result_sets.count} self-registered users"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in https://github.com/jamis/bulk_insert/issues/35, with credit to butnaruandrei. I had to create the bulk_insert object first, then call .add() later...as opposed to passing a block to bulk_insert with .add() within.

IMPORTANT: I also had to add `inserter.save!` after all add's. Without this, the last half-batch never gets saved...where it did get saved when passing a block in. This was not obvious at first, as everything *seemed* to be working...but the last few records were not saved without it.

This code works correctly:

```
columns = %i[first_name, last_name, email, referal]

inserter = User.bulk_insert(*columns, ignore: true, return_primary_keys: true) 
inserter.set_size = BATCH_SIZE

registrants.select(:fname, :lname, :email).find_in_batches(batch_size: BATCH_SIZE) do |batch|
  batch.each do |reg|
    inserter.add [reg.fname, reg.lname, reg.email, 'self-registered']
  end
end

inserter.save!
count = inserter.result_sets.map(&:rows).flatten.count

puts "added #{count} self-registered users"
```

Comment: Not quite related to the question, but to get the actual count of the records, you have to dig into each result_set and count the rows within each, as shown in the `count = inserter.result_sets.map(&:rows).flatten.count` line.